# Change label size per screen size xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin.forms to do an app and I perceived that to use the same size to letter to ios devices is not working: on 7 plus it works well, but on iphone 5 it's a Big letter for the size of the screen...
Do someone know a way to do letter with scallable size, or change the size for a specific device or type of screen size?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there it in xamarin.forms???

Comment: Hi Agaain Diegoo

Comment: I thought, thanks  :(

Comment: there are multiple questions and answers on this topic, both here on SO, and on Xamarin forums. Search for one of two approaches:  a) If you simply want to scale everything proportional to the screen size, look for answers that define sizes as a percent of the **pixel height or width** of the device.  b) A more sophisticated approach, that allows more content (e.g. more rows of a list) to show on larger phones, but also increases font size somewhat, is to have a size formula based on **device metrics (dp width and height)**; e.g. a size that grows with Sqrt of device width/height/or diagonal.

Answer (score 7):

You can refer following samples:

1. Estimate font-size for visual consistency - ([docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Estimated_font_sizes) |
   [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/blob/master/Chapter05/FontSizes/FontSizes/FontSizes/FontSizesPage.cs#L53))

   ```
   // Resolution in device-independent units per inch.
   double resolution = 160;

   // Do some numeric point sizes.
   int[] ptSizes = { 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };

   // Select numeric point size you need from ptSize[] array 
   double ptSize = 4;

   // this is your new visually consistent font-size.
   var fontSize = resolution * ptSize / 72;
   ```
2. Fitting text to available size - ([docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Fitting_text_to_available_size) |
   [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/blob/master/Chapter05/EstimatedFontSize/EstimatedFontSize/EstimatedFontSize/EstimatedFontSizePage.cs#L51))

   ```
   double lineHeight = Device.OnPlatform(1.2, 1.2, 1.3);//TODO: Change this to Device.RuntimePlatform
   double charWidth = 0.5;

   int charCount = text.Length;

   var view = this.Parent;
   // Because:
   //   lineCount = view.Height / (lineHeight * fontSize)
   //   charsPerLine = view.Width / (charWidth * fontSize)
   //   charCount = lineCount * charsPerLine
   // Hence, solving for fontSize:
   int fontSize = (int)Math.Sqrt(view.Width * view.Height /
                       (charCount * lineHeight * charWidth));
   ```

Comment: but the resolution is dinamic, right?
why Do you set a static size in double resolution = 160?

Comment: And is 72 a default value? (first example)
I'm a kind of confused, sorry

Comment: Please refer the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05/#Pixels_points_dps_DIPs_and_DIUs) - Xamarin always works with density independent pixels which is 1/160th of an inch; and traditionally in mac-world those units are 1/72th of an inch. Hence the calculation. The link explains it all.

Comment: Also - I wasn't sure whether you wanted consistent font-size - or just fit text according available width and height. So I added both examples. I think second example is more suited for your needs. The font-size won't be consistent, but it will always scale as per available space. So, on a screen with less width, the font-size will automatically get smaller.

Comment: IMHO, This doesn't answer the question. #2 is a different situation. #1 doesn't help with different physical size screens. And converting to point sizes is irrelevant for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Since the resolution value is 160 it doesn't serve the purpose of different screen sizes to have consistent font size.