# How FontSize is not changed on different devices in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Everyone let me know that I have a question about setting FontSize for Label: I set FontSize for Label A. For example: I tested on SSS8, I found it to be ok, but I tested it on other devices: Redmi Note 8, .... then it's big letters, it's too big for others, it's too small than expected.

Here is an example I set up Label:

```
<Label Text="Label Title" Margin="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource QuicksandRegular}" TextColor="#fff" FontSize="13"></Label>
```

So what is the solution to this problem? Looking for solutions from everyone. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. It will depend on the platform and the device, and the accesibility settings of that device.

Comment: There are lots of questions on this topic, you can search the answer for how to set font as a percent of the  pixel height or width of the device , e.g this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348647/change-label-size-per-screen-size-xamarin-forms .